# How to create an Approval Workflow with a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, approval-process

I am trying to make a SharePoint workflow that works with a Document Library.

A user is suppose to Drop in their document and the Workflow is suppose to kick off in squential order of the Approvers. How can I accomplish this? Can an OOB Approval workflow help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For workflow on the document or item refer to this article : https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-an-Approval-workflow-fd6dc3ed-85b9-4c96-89c0-fc3a3c31448f#bm3

and this https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Configure-a-site-list-or-library-to-require-approval-of-items-or-files-7f765a32-741d-4314-b27f-9b785437518c

You can also refer to this answer about for details about Content Approval

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/137436/49449

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would start with the out of box approval workflow and then customize with SharePoint Designer from there.

Comment: I am I customizing the OOB Workflow or is there something that I need to do to the library's settings? I understand that Content Approval in the Library can allow the document to view or not.